# Confidence Interval Algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to write a C++ program for parameter estimation(with Confidence Interval information) of an Exponentially distributed data set. I understand that $\lambda \bar{X} \sim \Gamma(n, n)$. To come up with numeric values of lower/higher confidence intervals for a specified $\alpha$, I need to be able to compute Inverse Gamma. Could you please point me to some algorithms?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to be able to compute confidence intervals for the estimate of the mean coming from $n$ outcomes from an exponential distribution?

Comment: Exactly. Computing the mean hence the $\lambda$ parameter is straightforward. But I also need to provide upper and lower confidence intervals for a given $\alpha$. Just like Matlab does.

Answer (score 0):

Either I misunderstand the problem, or you are making it more
difficult than necessary.

Let $L$ and $U$ cut probability $\alpha/2$
from the lower and upper tails of $Gamma(shape=n,rate=n),$
Then a $1 - \alpha$ confidence interval for $\lambda$ is found
as follows: 
$$P(L < \lambda \bar X < U) = P(L/\bar X < \lambda < U/\bar X) = 1-\alpha,$$
so the desired CI is $(L/\bar X,\; U/\bar X)$.

It is not difficult to program numerical integration to find $U$ and
$L$ because the PDF of $Gamma(n,n)$ can be evaluated. Alternatively, I'm sure
there must be a compiled FORTRAN program in the IMSL library of
statistical algorithms that can be called from C++.

In particular, if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{25}$ is a random sample
from $Exp(rate = .2),$ we might have the following sample (rounded to 3 places):

```
  1.515  0.187  6.270  3.291  3.597 10.680  1.572 22.555  4.924  0.063
  0.214  0.465 19.042  2.467  4.663  2.101  7.597 10.053  0.017  5.627
 12.124  7.579  0.735 11.290  4.153
```

The sample mean is $\bar X = 5.711.$ The cut-off points for a 95%
CI from R are

```
 qgamma(c(.025,.975), 25, 25)
 ## 0.6471473 1.4284039
```

so that the 95% CI is

```
 qgamma(c(.025,.975), 25, 25)/mean(x)
 ## 0.1133112 0.2501040
```

The (slightly biased) maximum likelihood estimator of of $\lambda$
in this example is $\hat \lambda = 1/\bar X =  0.175,$ which
is contained in the CI, but not exactly at the center of it,
owing to the skewness of the distributions involved.

The Wikipedia article on 'exponential distribution' shows
how to get essentially the same CI using printed tables of the
chi-squared distribution. (The chi-squared distribution is a
member of the gamma family of distributions, so an equivalent
expression is feasible.)

Comment: See item 1376391 on this site for numerical integration using gamma PDF. (Related, but not exactly your problem.)